# VB.NET SQL Update Table Using Listbox As Identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, listbox, sql-update

Hi I'm just learning how handle SQL statements using vb.net. My problem is how do I update my table using the items in listbox as an identifier. 
My SQL query is working.
    *update tblBillingSched set Status = 'paid'
where BillNum = 'MA5'*

Here's the revised code:

```
    Private Sub btnPostAdvancedPayment_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPostAdvancedPayment.Click

    Dim connection_string As String = "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=CreditAndCollection;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connection_string)
    connection.Open()
    Dim SQLCmd As SqlCommand
    Dim sSQL As String = "UPDATE tblBillingSched SET Status = 'Paid' WHERE BillNum = "
    If MessageBox.Show("Continue to Save?", " ", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim firstTime As Boolean = True
        For Each item In lstBillNum.Items
            If (item IsNot Nothing AndAlso item.ToString().Trim().Length > 0) Then
                If (firstTime) Then
                    firstTime = False
                Else
                    sSQL = sSQL & " OR BillNum = "
                End If
                sSQL = sSQL & "'" & item.ToString() & "'"
            End If
        Next
        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(sSQL, Connection)
        SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MessageBox.Show("Client Record Successfully Saved!", " ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        connection.Close()
        SQLCmd.Dispose()
    ElseIf DialogResult.Cancel Then
        MessageBox.Show("Saving Cancelled!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are after. You mean changing the connecting string from BillNum = lstBillNum.SelectedValue" to a loop going through all the names and values in the ListBox? How are you defining your ListBox?

Comment: Hi, for example I have items(MA5, MA6, MA7) inside my listbox. Then I want to update my table using the listbox items in where clause.

update tblBillingSched set Status = 'paid' where BillNum = 'items in my listbox'

Comment: SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(sSQL, Connection) has to be AFTER the sSQL string is defined (in the loop). I have updated your code. Please, test it and let me know how it goes.

Comment: No problem. But a recommendation for next time: learn to debug a code and to see the values of each variable. In this way you would quickly locate where the problem might be (in your previous code, you would have seen that the sSQL value in the connection wasn't the same one than what it came from the loop).

Comment: I'll take your advice Sir @varocarbas. I still have a lot to learn more in programming. Thanks again. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you are after a loop on these lines:

```
Dim sSQL As String = "UPDATE tblBillingSched SET Status = 'paid' WHERE BillNum = "

Dim firstTime As Boolean = True
For Each item In lstBillNum.Items
    If (item IsNot Nothing AndAlso item.ToString().Trim().Length > 0) Then
        If (firstTime) Then
            firstTime = False
        Else
            sSQL = sSQL & " OR BillNum = "
        End If
        sSQL = sSQL & "'" & item.ToString() & "'"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi Varocarbas,
I tried to insert your code and I can see in quick watch that my Listbox item was successfully added in my sql query but when I save it my table is still not updated. Please help.

Comment: @Sishan I cannot test the query in this moment, but it should be OK. You can try to input some brackets (although shouldn't be required) to see if it works in this way. First thing to check is whether the string is properly formed (sSQL after the loop; what should be the case, if the items in the ListBox are OK). Second thing is confirming that the connection is OK and that you don't need to perform any update in the query. I cannot confirm this last issue for you. Do some tests, find a query delivering exactly what you want and I might update my code to account for the required variations.

Comment: @Sishan also bear in mind that I don't know the contents in your DB and how they match your ListBox items. My answer assumes that your previous code worked fine and that all the items in the ListBox matched values in your DB. Also I am not sure what "is still not updated" means: no value, some values? If you want to get quick help, better ask for the kind of help I (or any other person) is in a position to provide: tell the inputs (sSQL string after the loop) and the contents in your DB (ideally, do the testing by your own).

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, here's what happened to the sSQL after the execution of the loop.
`sSQL = "UPDATE tblBillingSched SET Status = 'Paid' WHERE BillNum = 'MA10'"`
but when checking my database Status column is still null.
I just revised the code above.

Comment: @Sishan !!! you wrote it wrongly. You have to use the query after assigning a value to sSQL (after the loop). I will update your question now. Please, test the updated code.

Comment: @Vacocarbas, yes i have that row. I think I have no problem in my DB connection because when I tried to manually input a value in my BillNum the the row updated. Here's the example `Dim sSQL As String = "UPDATE tblBillingSched SET Status = 'Paid' WHERE BillNum = "` then I manually input MA10 `Dim sSQL As String = "UPDATE tblBillingSched SET Status = 'Paid' WHERE BillNum = 'MA10'"`.

Comment: @Sishan(my nick is VaRocarbas). I have explained above what was your problem: you wrote it wrongly (put my code in the wrong place), I have updated your code: please, test it and confirm that it works.

Comment: @Sishan you wrote SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(sSQL, Connection) before the loop and thus sSQL wasn't the one coming from my code but the original version you had.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim dt as date = CDate(DateTime.Today).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
        Try
            Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
            cn.ConnectionString = GetConnectionStringByName("FD_project.My.MySettings.fixedepoConnectionString")
             Dim sSQL As String = "UPDATE fixdeporeg SET approval = 'A', a_user = 'CFO', " & _
                                                        "app_date = # " & dt & "# WHERE slno = "
            If MessageBox.Show("Continue to Save?", " ", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim firstTime As Boolean = True
                For x As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
                    If (firstTime) Then
                        firstTime = False
                    Else
                        sSQL = sSQL & " OR slno = "
                    End If
                    'sSQL = sSQL & "'" & item.ToString() & "'"
                    sSQL = sSQL & CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(x).item("slno")
                Next
                Dim SQLCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, cn)
                MessageBox.Show(sSQL)
                cn.Open()
                'dt = cmd1.ExecuteScalar()
                SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cn.Close()
            ElseIf DialogResult.Cancel Then
                MessageBox.Show("Saving Cancelled!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```